# bash - using getopts with an associative array in a bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, getopts

I'm using `getopts` along with an `associate array` in my code below.
What I can't figure out is how to correctly call my values, given that I'm asking for (2) alias(s) using the same flag.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

usage () {
    echo "Usage: $0 -c alias1  -c alias2"
}

while getopts ":c:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    c) alias="$OPTARG";;
    *) echo "Error unknown option -$OPTARG"
       usage
       exit 1
       ;;
  esac
done

# Testing use off array
declare -A alias=( [alias1]=myhost-01.com \
                   [alias2]=myhost-02.com \
                   [alias3]=myhost-03.com \
                   [alias4]=myhost-04.com )

echo "This is my source host:${alias}"
echo "This is my target host:${alias}"
```

This is how I would like to execute it (or better suggeested way):

```
-bash-4.1$ ./test-array2.sh -c alias1 -c alias4
This is my source host:
This is my target host:
```

Obviously, I'm not getting my expected result which would be this:

```
This is my source host: myhost-01.com
This is my target host: myhost-04.com
```

How can I do this? I want to pass in (2) aliases which uses my alias mapping (associative array) to grab the correct key value pair or maybe my approach is wrong and I can't use `-c` twice? Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, array access is `${array[$index]}`. So I believe the source would be `${alias[alias1]}`, and the target `${alias[alias4]}`. I would normally use indices, i.e. `0` insteead of `alias1`, etc., but that's me. I don't do a lot with Bash, though.

Comment: so call it by number on the command line? `./test-array2.sh -c 0 -c3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array to store the aliases e.g.

```
aliases=()
while getopts ":c:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        c) aliases+=( "$OPTARG" );;
    # ...
    esac
done
```

And then you use the this array to index your associative array:

```
echo "This is my source host:${alias_to_host[${aliases[0]}]}"
echo "This is my target host:${alias_to_host[${aliases[1]}]}"
```

But if the input options are representing aliases for source and  destination host and there always is exactly two hosts, it would be much cleaner to use separate options (e.g. `-s` and `-d`) and separate variables for these than reusing the switch `-c`:

```
# ...
    case $opt in
        s) source=$OPTARG;;
        d) destination=$OPTARG;;
        # ...
    esac
# ...

echo "This is my source host:${alias_to_host[$source]}"
echo "This is my target host:${alias_to_host[$destination]}"
```

Comment: I agree, using 2 switches would be cleaner.  But in my `getopts`, can I call `aliases` with two different switches?

Comment: Yes, you could still use the same `alias_to_host` map. Please note that I renamed your original `alias` associative array to `alias_to_host` to be more descriptive.

Comment: Perfect! Works great. Thanks :-)